# How can I generate multiple files by looping over values and making HTTP call for each?

Tags: java, groovy, mule, esb

Roughly: On regular intervals I make calls to the same host with different paths, e.g.,

- http://lvh.me/foo
- http://lvh.me/bar
- http://lvh.me/baz

For each of those:

- Run the same data transform
- Write a specifically-named file with results

I currently use a Quartz connector to fire off a single URI's processing. Instead I'd like to fire off something that uses the same sub-flow(s) across the collection of URIs. I can start a flow from a script component, but I need to know how to pass a value (the URI, or URI fragment, at least) to that script.

Other options I've considered:

- Hit a Mule HTTP endpoint with the values from my script, use it in the sub-flow(s)
- Throw a value in a message queue, consume them in a thin wrapper around the sub-flow(s)

I'm open to better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one flow:

- Use either a `poll` scope or `quartz` endpoint to generate a message with a `List` payload that contains one string per path (say, `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`).
- Add a collection splitter to split this message into n messages
- Finish a parameterized outbound HTTP endpoint that has an address like `http://lvh.me/#[message.payload]`

The above assumes you do an HTTP `GET` towards `lvh.me`. If you do a post, you'll need to copy the payload in a flowVar, create the right payload then use the flowVar and payload in the HTTP outbound endpoint performing the `POST`.